# S3 multithreaded download library

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have a java application that needs to do fast and reliable downloads from Amazon's S3.  Ideally, I'd use something like the AWS SDK's TransferManager ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html ), except I'd like to process the data in a streaming fashion, without having to stage all the downloaded data on local disk.

Ideally, the library would have an interface similar to AmazonS3#getObject(), but the implementation would be faster and more robust.  Even better, the library would support pre-fetching for multiple S3 objects: I could give it a list of objects that I want to download eventually, then consume a sequence of streams for each object quickly.  It's ok if the library has to use a lot of RAM to do the pre-fetching.

Does anybody know of a library that has some/all of these features?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [minio-java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java)

> Java Library for Amazon S3 Compatible Cloud Storage

*io.minio.MinioClient.getObject* returns *InputStream* [[example]](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/GetObject.java) and you could do multiple *getObject* where each call returns individual *InputStream*.

```
MinioClient s3Client = new MinioClient("https://s3.amazonaws.com", "YOUR-ACCESSKEYID", "YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY");
InputStream stream1 = s3Client.getObject("my-bucketname", "my-objectname1");
InputStream stream2 = s3Client.getObject("my-bucketname", "my-objectname2");
```

Here, the streams are not pre-fetched.  If pre-fetching is hard requirement, you could use another variant of *getObject*

> public void getObject(String bucketName, String objectName, String fileName)

Advantage of using this method is, it resumes previous *getObject* if any.

```
MinioClient s3Client = new MinioClient("https://s3.amazonaws.com", "YOUR-ACCESSKEYID", "YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY");
s3Client.getObject("my-bucketname", "my-objectname1", "/mycachedir/my-objectname1");
s3Client.getObject("my-bucketname", "my-objectname2", "/mycachedir/my-objectname2");
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, but looking at the code, a call to getObject() maps to a single HTTP GET request: https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/a8c9ffa1919e47b743dffabc9eb756847016263a/src/main/java/io/minio/MinioClient.java#L487 That's going to run into similar robustness and speed limitations with the AWS SDK's implementation of getObject().  The resume feature you mention for the overload that takes a filename looks nice (and can help make things more robust), but ideally I could recover from a closed connection without having to store the whole download on disk.